# Ошибка с резким закрытием программы в QT creator при создании Змейки

Tags: c++, qt, разработка-игр

На этапе компиляции вылетает ошибка 
`The program has unexpectedly finished.
The process was ended forcefully.`

**Fruit.h**

```
#define FRUIT_H
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGradient>

class Fruit : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{

    public:
         Fruit(QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr);

    private:
        int time;
        QPoint point;
        QGraphicsEllipseItem* elipse;
        QRadialGradient radi;


    signals:



};

#endif // FRUIT_H
```

**Snakegame.h**

```
#define SNAKEGAME_H

#include <QGraphicsView>



class Snakegame : public QGraphicsView
{
    public:
        Snakegame(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
        QGraphicsScene* scene;

    private:




};

#endif // SNAKEGAME_H
```

**Fruit.cpp**

```
Fruit::Fruit(QGraphicsItem *parent):QGraphicsEllipseItem(parent)
{
elipse->setRect(0,0,100,100);
radi.setColorAt(0,Qt::blue);
radi.setColorAt(0.5,Qt::green);
radi.setColorAt(1,Qt::red);
elipse->setBrush(radi);

}
```

**snakegame.cpp**

```
#include <fruit.h>

Snakegame::Snakegame(QWidget* parent):QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    Fruit *fru = new Fruit();
    scene->addItem(fru);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    setScene(scene);
    show();

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <fruit.h>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Snakegame *snakegame = new Snakegame();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: **На этапе компиляции вылетает ошибка** Т.е. у вас следает не ваша программа, а сам компилятор не может ее скомпилировать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот неужели сложно просто посмотреть те пару строк что вы написали прежде чем публиковать вопрос?

```cpp
scene->addItem(fru);
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
```

У вас банальное обращение по невалидному указателю

PS освойте дебагер